# NSLog from appDelegate

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nslog

Inside AppDelegate.m I am trying to grab the stuff from a string I am getting from an incoming URL. I'm not sure why NSLog is not printing anything out...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions openURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    // incoming URL...
    // i.e.  palsvid://blabla.com/foo.php?request=laa&id=1004


    NSString *q = [url query];

    NSLog(@"%@",q); // Does not log anything! Even with a hard coded string!

    NSArray *pairs = [q componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    // ...
```

Am I doing something wrong? I update plist to accept the url, now I want to parse it.

Eventually I will take this data and use it in my ViewController. NSLog works in the ViewController methods...

Thanks

Comment: If it's not logging anything, even a hard-coded string, either it's not getting called or you're running a different version of the app than you think. (That happened to me today!) Could you display the string to the screen some other way, like by setting the text of a label or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong method signature so your method is never called. There is no `openURL:` parameter. You want:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // your code here
}
```

That is called when you app is started from scratch.

To handle your app being called from another app or being sent a URL, you need to implement the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    // process URL here
}
```

Please read the docs for `UIApplicationDelegate` as well as the related app life cycle docs.